# Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times [PHPUnit]

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I've been testing, adding and removing lines to see where the problem is. I've managed to cut so many lines that essentially my test looks like that ( of course to see what is wrong, I'm aware this isn't proper test ):

```
public function test()
{
     $invoice = new Invoice();
     $invoiceRepository = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
      $invoiceRepository->expects($this->once())
            ->method('findOneByNextNote')
            ->will($this->returnValue($invoice));

      $invoiceRepository->findOneByNextNote();
}
```

and still doesn't work! I'm getting an error from the title:

> Expectation failed for method name is equal to
>   < string:findOneByNextNote > when invoked 1 time(s). Method was expected
>   to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

What am I missing?

Comment: We don't know what you are missing, but we are missing the code that is tested;)

Comment: I don't know exactly how your mock framework works but with other frameworks you have to "start" your mocks. Like `EasyMock.replay(mockObject)`

Comment: @lukelazarovic but my test looks like that right now! and is still not working.

Comment: I believe the problem is that no real method called "findOneByNextNote" is actually called, as this is delegated to the __call method of EntityRepository by method overloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify which method you want to mock (instead of the full class) so the behaviour of the class, so muck only the method you want to test as follow:

```
public function testFindOne()
{
    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $invoiceRepository = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')
        ->setMethods(array('findOneByNextNote'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $invoiceRepository->expects($this->once())
        ->method('findOneByNextNote')
        ->will($this->returnValue($invoice));

    $invoiceRepository->findOneByNextNote();
}
```

So the assertion work as expected

Hope this helps

Comment: why someone have downvote without any explaination? Is a working, tested solution to the problem described in the question

Comment: I don't believe this solution is ideal, you could just as well go mock stdClass then instead of the repository class.

Comment: setMethods() is deprecated. One should use addMethods() and onlyMethods() instead

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes this misunderstanding appear when you call the method before "expects()" instructions. So the code looks great but didn't work.

Example **bad**:

```
    $mock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder(YourClass::class)
        ->setMethods(['emit'])
        ->getMock();

    $mock->emit();
    $mock->expects($this->once())->method('emit');

    //Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

Example **good**:

```
    $mock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder(YourClass::class)
        ->setMethods(['emit'])
        ->getMock();

    $mock->expects($this->once())->method('emit');
    $mock->emit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion fails because the EntityRepository does in fact not have an implemented method named `findOneByNextNote`, and therefore it is also never called.

However, the magic `__call` method is implemented (and calling `findOneByNextNote` will be delegated to that method by the PHP engine's method overloading), so you could assert that this method is called to fix your assertion.

A probably better solution would be to actually write a concrete InvoiceRepository class (and I'd suggest even an interface) with that particular method, and mock this class or interface instead.